# How to share environment variables across AWS CodeDeploy steps?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-code-deploy

I am working on a new deployment strategy that leverages AWS CodeDeploy. The project I work on has many environments (e.g: preproduction, production) and instances (e.g: EMEA, US, APAC).

I have the basic scaffolding working ok but I noticed environment variables set in the **BeforeInstall** hook can not be retrieved from other steps (for instance, **AfterInstall**).

Is there a way to share environment variables across AWS CodeDeploy steps?

**Content of appspec.yml:**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /tmp/code-deploy
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: utils/delivery/aws/CodeDeploy/before_install.sh
      timeout: 300
  AfterInstall:
    - location: utils/delivery/aws/CodeDeploy/after_install.sh
      timeout: 300
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: utils/delivery/aws/CodeDeploy/application_start.sh
      timeout: 300
  ValidateService:
    - location: utils/delivery/aws/CodeDeploy/validate_service.sh
      timeout: 300
```

I set an environment variable in **before_install.sh**:

```
export ENVIRONMENT=preprod
```

And if I reference it in **after_install.sh**:

```
$ echo $ENVIRONMENT
$
```

Nothing.

Thank you for your help on this one!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the `export` into a temporary file, and then, `source` that file.  So within before_install.sh:

```
ENVIRONMENT="preprod"  
echo "export ENVIRONMENT=\"$ENVIRONMENT\"" > "/path/to/file"
```

Note: With this method, you are no longer exporting the variable in before_install.sh.  You are simply writing a file to be sourced in after_install.sh:

```
source "/path/to/file"
echo "$ENVIRONMENT"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should consider setting those variables up in the userdata phase of the instance launch, instead of at deploy time. This allows them to be available to all codedeploy scripts during the life of the instance.

The type of data you describe eg Environment is more associated with the instance itself, and would not normally change during code deployment.

In your Userdata you would set an instance level variable like this:

```
export ENVIRONMENT="preprod"  >> /etc/environment
```

Another advantage of this approach is that your app itself may want to consult these variables when it launches, to provide environment specific configuration.

If you use Cloudformation, you can set the environment up as a parameter, and pass that on to the user data script. In this way, you can launch the stack and its resources with the appropriate parameters, and launch consistent instances for any environment.

Comment: Can you explain what is the "userdata phase" the terminology is not clear to me. thx

Comment: Yeah it's a weird name really. Think of the instance userdata as a startup script for your instance. You can initialize all your variables in that script as shown above. For more info see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: This actually doesn't work. Environment variables set in /etc/environment are not visible to codedeploy scripts.

Comment: It's always worked for me on Ubuntu 16. Has anything changed? See https://serverfault.com/questions/375252/what-is-the-best-place-to-setup-system-wide-environment-variables-on-linux

Comment: As far as I've been able to ascertain, regardless of how the environment variables are set, they're still not visible to appspec hook scripts. The only way I was able to get it to work was to manually parse my environment file inside the hook scripts.